# Replace bad values with mean of pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'd like to replace bad values `negative values(-666)` and `NaNs` in a pandas series with grouped or aggregated mean value. Sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'cat': ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
                   'val': [np.nan, 10, 4, 5, -666, -666, 15, 20, 10]
                 })
```

Expected output:

```
 A 10
 B 10
 C 4
 A 5
 B 15
 C 5
 A 15
 B 20
 C 10
```

How do I fix the bad values with grouped mean?

Comment: IIUC, there's a typo in the 6th row. The mean value of positive "C"s is 7 not 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `where` to mask the unwanted values; then replace them using the outcome of `groupby` + transform `mean`:

```
tmp = df['val'].where(lambda x: x>0)
df['val'] = tmp.fillna(tmp.groupby(df['cat']).transform('mean'))
```

We can also derive the same result using the one-liner below (less efficient than the one above):

```
df['val'] = df['val'].where(lambda x: x>0, df.groupby('cat')['val'].transform(lambda x: x[x>0].mean()))
```

Output:

```
  cat   val
0   A  10.0
1   B  10.0
2   C   4.0
3   A   5.0
4   B  15.0
5   C   7.0
6   A  15.0
7   B  20.0
8   C  10.0
```